# How can I set a tab to open 50% in desktop and 100% in mobile using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I want a tab that will open 50% in window and 100% on mobile phone, how can I achieve this by using js. Here is my js fill which I am using right now.

```js
    <script>
        function openNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidecmnt").style.width = "100%";
        }
        
        function closeNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidecmnt").style.width = "0";
        }
    </script>
```

Html file

```html
    <div id="mySidecmnt" class="sidecmnt">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtnsty" onclick="closeNav()"><svg width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 25 25" class="hp"><path d="M18.13 6.11l-5.61 5.61-5.6-5.61-.81.8 5.61 5.61-5.61 5.61.8.8 5.61-5.6 5.61 5.6.8-.8-5.6-5.6 5.6-5.62"></path></svg></a>
                
        <!-- comments -->
        <?php 
            if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        ?>
        <!-- end comments -->
    </div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">open</span>
```

Comment: Not with `js` but using `css` you can easily achieve this with `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { #mySidecmnt { width: 100% } }`  & `@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) { #mySidecmnt { width: 50% } }` for reference check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp. You can change `max-width` according to your need.

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether it is mobile device with below code from this answer [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/9695286). And apply condition `if (mobileCheck())` in `openNav` function as below.

```
window.mobileCheck = function() {
  let check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};

function openNav() {
  if (mobileCheck()) {
    document.getElementById("mySidecmnt").style.width = "100%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidecmnt").style.width = "50%";
  }
}
```